# how to express a sentence with is +verb+ing

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I would like to express my sentence using is +verb+ing however, I feel the grammar is wrong.

*The one main advantagae of using model A is allowing specifying different marginal distribution for each variable*

I feel that the grammar is worng for *allowing specifying*

Is my sentence correct? if not, then how can I edit it?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: *The one main advantage of using model A is* ***that it allows the specification of*** *different marginal distributions for each variable.* Note that you need to use a plural *specifications*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think consecutive -ing verbs are ungrammatical - but they definitely sound jarring to a native speaker.

I find that the *-ing* and *to*-forms can often be used interchangeably. With something like your example, I look for which of the two *-ing* verbs is showing intention, and which shows consequence. I then use the *to*-form to show the intention.

So, for your example, this is one option I would consider:

> The one main advantage of using model A is to allow the specifying of
>   different marginal distribution for each variable.

While that method will work in most situations, it is not always best. You could use "it allows" instead of "to allow". Another option is "specification" instead of "specifying".